# show maximum labels in chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts

I am creating a project using JavaScript. In my project i am integrating google charts, In my chart i want to show only five labels.I don't know how can i do this.Here is code:

```
var N = 10;
// Array filled with N values at '0'
var zero_array = [];

for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    zero_array.push(0);

// The data of the chart, describe the differents sets of data you want with points, colors...
var data = {
        labels: zero_array,
        datasets:  [
            {
                 showXLabels: 5,
                label: zero_array, // Name of the line
                data: zero_array, // data to represent
                // The following makes the line way less ugly
                fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",

            }
        ]
};

// We wait for everything to be loaded
window.onload = function main() {

    // Get the context of the canvas
    var ctx = document.getElementById("line_example").getContext("2d");

    // Create the Chart object
    var line_example_chart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);

    // Used for the labels on the X axis
    var label_idx = 1;

    // Function to execute to remove then add a new random value to the chart
    function rand_value() {
        // Generate a random integer
        var rand_val = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

        // Remove the point at the far left of the chart
        line_example_chart.removeData();

        // Add the random value at the far right of the chart
        line_example_chart.addData([rand_val], label_idx++);
    }
    // Run rand_value() every 2 seconds
    window.setInterval(rand_value, 2000);
}
```

plunker link:
  https://plnkr.co/edit/fat6hRS4lFnAEjoiSORW?p=preview

please help.

Comment: Do you mean like showing only 5 points at a time?

Comment: yes................ @allu

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, just change N to 5:

```
var N = 5;
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/eJP4G6bYuGB5NaYvcQGX?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Please update below line and you can see only 5 nodes in your chart

var N = 5;